Why Premake can't find my header inside a folder?
I'm using premake with vscode. It works fine with ogre3d but when it turns to raylib, Everything became a mess because I cannot find the reason why It continuously appears:
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: raylib.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <raylib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Here is my link to the project for better observation. https://github.com/DPthang411/raylib-learning

Here, you should show whole required information, so premake5.lua file and structure of directory.

As it is Christmas, PR done to fix your script.

Also asked on premake github there.
